# ¿formas de insertar una tabla en un modal con Bootstrap 4?

Tags: php, bootstrap, modal, table

Parece una pavada pero llevo horas intentando resolverlo! lo que me sucede es que quiero mostrar una simple tabla en un modal, a lo cual la tabla que esta situado en el div.modal-body me lo carga dentro de la pagina principal y no dentro del modal... alguna ayuda plisss

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger agregarproductos" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#agregarProductos">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Agregar productos
                        </button>

<!-- Modal AGREGAR PRODUCTOS-->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="agregarProductos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>Buscar Productos</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                <th>Codigo</th>
                                    <th>Producto</th>
                                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                                    <th>Precio</th>
                                    <th>Agregar</th>
                                </tr>                                    
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>                           
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal AGREGAR-->
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

explico la captura: el primer encabezado es el de la pagina principal y el segundo es el que deberia aparecer en el modal juntamente con el boton cerrar que pertenece al div.modal-footer

Comment: Revisa si no estan cargando alguna libreria o busca errores en la consola del navegador, el codigo carga bien mira -> https://jsfiddle.net/s16dvfc4/

Comment: Igual puede ser un <div> mal cerrado

Comment: Por favor, 2 cosas, muestra el código completo a ver si no te falta algo. Y por otra parte muestra los errores de la consola del navegador o de Network en el caso que aparezcan alla.